# Why is the pendulum swing dependent on the string length?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, dimensional-analysis

Though this seems obvious, the longer the string length, the longer the time period. But my question is why does this exactly happen, and how do you explain it with equations?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pendulum_(mathematics)

Comment: Hint: Try displacing the pendulum an angle $\theta$ and then calculate the net torque on it. Later assume $\theta$ to be small and substitute $\sin{\theta}$ by $\theta$

Answer (score 1):

For a pendulum of mass $m$ and length $\ell$ in a gravitational field $g$, the combination
$$
\Pi_0=\frac{T^2 g}{\ell}
$$
(independent of the mass $m$) is dimensionless.  Thus
\begin{align}
T\sim \sqrt{\frac{\ell}{g}}
\end{align}
and the period must depend on the square root of the length.

Answer (score 0):

Time period of pendulum is $T=2\pi\sqrt{l/g}$ we derive this equation using simple torque equation, so you can clearly understand that how the time period related to length.
Note since you have no shown your efforts so I have not derived the derivation